# How to read System.Net.Mail.Attachment.ContentStream properties?

Tags: vb.net, stream, email-attachments, mailmessage

I'm looking for a way to read the Name property of the .NET  Attachment.Content Stream I can see the property when I setup a watch, but when I try accessing I don't see the "Name" property show up. I need to get the file location with the "C:\Test123.pdf", I've found a way to get the file name...but I need its location/path.

[image]

Comment: Could be wrong about this, if you look at the strm type in the watch it gives you a bit of a clue.  You can see it's been cast to System.IO.FileStream, in your code, your working with System.IO.Stream.  I think if you change Dim strm as New System.IO.FileStream you will find your missing properties

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!